# Combining data from two Controllers into a single model - Backend or Frontend?

Tags: angular, typescript, asp.net-core

I have two controllers and corresponding services and dbcontexts that interacts with the database.

1. User
2. File

File controller deals with **File** model that has the following properties

```
Filename,Date Created,User id
```

**User** model has the following

```
User id,email
```

So, in this scenario **i want to display all the users in a table and the number of files he/she has created so far**.
As these two data are obtained from two different controllers should the processing be done in Angular side or should i create an aggregator class to combine the data into a single model?

Comment: How you call both data from and from where ?

Comment: As always, it depends on the details, but the most common approach should be to use EF to join the data and return this combined data to the client.

Comment: @ChristophLütjen So i need to create another controller and corresponding combined model for this?

Comment: Yes, you create a new action (as part of an existing or new controller class). There you create a query that joins users and file counts and return the result. Search e.g. for ef core + left join + count to find examples, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48521550/ef-core-left-join-with-count